# What are the best practices for nested objects in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, class, object

This question has to do with best practices... please do not confuse it with premature optimization.

I noticed in .Net that deep object referencing takes quite some time to process when compared to flat or shallow objects. For example:

```
object1.object2.object3.object4.Property
```

... is not efficient since, I conclude, each object has to be de-referenced along the path. This is in contrast to C, where `Property`'s memory ref would be calculated by the compiler, rather than at run time.

Now, we obviously wouldn't take all the fields of object2+ and flatten them into object1 just for speed. The coding would be unwieldy and hard to manage. But the speed difference could be significant.

So my question is, "What is the best practice in building deep objects vs. flat(ish) objects?" And, further, is there any advantage to using structs where one is simply trying to group a number of fields together, such as:

```
public struct SizeData
{
    public long Written;
    public long Read;
    public int Size;
}
```

The two questions relate.

**EDIT**

To illustrate:

```
public class Leaf
{
    public int Property;
}

public class Depth1
{
    public Leaf Leaf;
}

public class Depth2
{
    public Depth1 Depth1;
}

public class Depth3
{
    public Depth2 Depth2;
}

private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Depth3 depth = new Depth3();
    depth.Depth2 = new Depth2();
    depth.Depth2.Depth1 = new Depth1();
    depth.Depth2.Depth1.Leaf = new Leaf();
    Leaf leaf = new Leaf();

    var T1 = Environment.TickCount;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
    {
        depth.Depth2.Depth1.Leaf.Property++;
    }

    var T2 = Environment.TickCount;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
    {
        leaf.Property++;
    }

    var T3 = Environment.TickCount;

    MessageBox.Show((T2 - T1).ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
        ((T3 - T2).ToString()));
}
```

Comment: Have you actually profiled this?  I'd be surprised if there was actually a noticable difference in the cost of working with "shallow" objects vs "deep" objects.

Comment: As your question is about best practices, deep object referencing exposes you to a high level of dependency. This is the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter

Comment: Saying that it takes "quite some time" to process deeply-nested object reference is totally wrong. Unless your idea of "quite some time" is a handful of nanoseconds.

Comment: Can you elaborate on and substantiate _in .Net that deep object referencing takes quite some time_ ?  Seems total nonsense to me.

Comment: You start by saying 'don't confuse it with premature optimization' but then say you're only concerned with speed constraints.  Being concerned about 5 pointer deference is prematurely optimizing.  It's the definition of premature optimizing.

Comment: @Kragen I have tested this and this is a big difference. try it.

Comment: @JsBangs your math is wrong. Nanoseconds * trillions of ops = real time.

Comment: @Kieren wow, this is supposed to be a friendly place. I am asking about a design pattern. I just happened to reference speed. I'm not even asking what is fastest - THAT would be a speed question.

Comment: I can't see any design patterns in your question, all I see is 'this isn't efficient since everything has to be dereferenced' which makes no sense unless you are talking about speed.  There is no design question here, you're talking about sacrificing design to favour speed.  That.. ..is.. ..premature.. ..optimisation.

Comment: @IanC Yes, but only if your application exists purely to derference things!  As soon as your application does anything of substance any perceptible difference will pale into insignificance.

Comment: @IanC: your illustration illustrates it on syntactical level, but not on semantical.

Comment: Is it not better to change the question title to "nested **objects**" instead of "nested **classes**"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only concern here IMHO is not speed, but dependency. Have you ever tried to refactor an application that frequently uses deep object nesting like this? It's a pain in the arse. Have a look at the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) (or as I say, the Guideline of Demeter). The idea is that instead of using

```
person.Address.ZipCode
```

you instead use something like

```
person.AddressZipCode
```

to avoid a dependency on the Address object. Is it faster? Maybe, if you implement it right. But I personally don't care because the speedup is really trivial. All I care about here is reducing dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, you shouldn't take the speed into consideration until you realize it's a bottleneck.

The classes/structs should be grouped purely logically: if you see that some class *is* a part of some other class, that it is needed *only* inside the bigger class and makes sense *only* inside the bigger class, then you should put it there and thus avoid polluting namespace. If you see that your smaller class is useful outside the bigger class, define it outside. That simple.

Summing it up: put your class/structure to the deepest appropriate level, but not deeper.

Examples:

1. `myCar.RegistrationDate.Year.IsLeap` makes perfect sense, and is much better than `myCar.IsRegistrationYearLeap`
2. `point.Coordinates.Cartesian.X` doesn't make much sense, `point.X` is much better.

Answer (score 3):

The term **nested class** is usually used to mean "nested type".

```
class Foo
{
   private class FoosHelper { .. }
}
```

The best practice here is to use them sparingly and prefer private.

---

But your example is not about nested classes but about **nested objects** instead:

```
 object1.object2.object3.object4.Property
```

The best practice would be: build a logical and cohesive object-model first and foremost.

Your suggestion of 'flattening' seems to be about sacrificing the core architecture for a tiny optimization. Not such a good idea.

---

And to the (only slightly) related **struct** question:

> is there any advantage to using structs where one is simply trying to group a number of fields together

No, usually not. There are rare case where you would need very large arrays of small types but in general using a struct brings only disadvantages.

Comment: Yes, I mean nested class objects. I heard the 64 bit JIT doesn't like structs, but not why. Do you know?

Comment: I wouldn't know about a 64/32 bit difference.

Answer (score 1):

Struct field will not have separate memory allocation then the enclosing object, so there is no difference how deep it is, if all of the nested are structs, it's computed by the compiler.

If you nest the reference types, they have to be dereferenced, and this is not any different from C++.